# Turning off Node.js/JavaScript assertions in production

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Java, assertions are only executed if a java argument is executed at startup.  Is there a similar option for assertions in Node.js?  As I understand it, assertions should not be used in production code.  Instead, the standard error handling mechanisms should be employed.

Comment: You'll have to specify what kind of assertions you're talking about. The language itself doesn't have assertions, other than what the environment itself might provide. Do you mean perhaps `console.assert()`?

Comment: @JJJ, I was using https://www.npmjs.com/package/assert.  I suppose the package is really meant only for use in testing.  Maybe I'd have to write something custom to mirror the Java assert functionality with the ability to turn it on or off.

Comment: I created a ticket on github to ask for the intention of the assert package. https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3266

Answer (score 0):

If you use a module like `assert` then you might turn off the assertions using a module like [`mock-require`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require) by putting empty functions in place of the actual `assert` functions.

But it would be more elegant to abstract away your assertions in your own module that would test the `process.env.NODE_ENV` and if it's equal to `"production"` wouldn't runn the assertions if that's what you want.

Although you need to consider if that is really what you want because it may hide some kinds of errors.